# What does LINK_TOKEN_POINTER do

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I am trying to get chainlink to work on harmony one block chain, I am trying to deploy a testing contract extending chainlinkclient.sol to test out the setup but for some reason it won't deploy.  I am wondering if it's because of the LINK_TOKEN_POINTER hardcoded to 0xC89bD4E1632D3A43CB03AAAd5262cbe4038Bc571.  Does anyone know what that address is?  Is it the same for all the ETH testnets (rinkeby, kovan, etc) and other chains as well?

I am trying to deploy the TestConsumer.sol contract onto the Harmony One chain but am getting an error.  I was able to get it to work on Kovan.

[image]

I suspect it might be due to the LINK_TOKEN_POINTER.  Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/evm-contracts/src/v0.4/ChainlinkClient.sol";
import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/evm-contracts/src/v0.4/vendor/Ownable.sol";

contract ATestnetConsumer is ChainlinkClient, Ownable {
  uint256 constant private ORACLE_PAYMENT = 1 * LINK;

  uint256 public currentPrice;
  int256 public changeDay;
  bytes32 public lastMarket;

  event RequestEthereumPriceFulfilled(
    bytes32 indexed requestId,
    uint256 indexed price
  );

  event RequestEthereumChangeFulfilled(
    bytes32 indexed requestId,
    int256 indexed change
  );

  event RequestEthereumLastMarket(
    bytes32 indexed requestId,
    bytes32 indexed market
  );

  constructor() public Ownable() {
    setPublicChainlinkToken();
  }

  function requestEthereumPrice(address _oracle, string _jobId)
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(stringToBytes32(_jobId), this, this.fulfillEthereumPrice.selector);
    req.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    req.add("path", "USD");
    req.addInt("times", 100);
    sendChainlinkRequestTo(_oracle, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
  }

  function requestEthereumChange(address _oracle, string _jobId)
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(stringToBytes32(_jobId), this, this.fulfillEthereumChange.selector);
    req.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    req.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.CHANGEPCTDAY");
    req.addInt("times", 1000000000);
    sendChainlinkRequestTo(_oracle, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
  }

  function requestEthereumLastMarket(address _oracle, string _jobId)
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(stringToBytes32(_jobId), this, this.fulfillEthereumLastMarket.selector);
    req.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    string[] memory path = new string[](4);
    path[0] = "RAW";
    path[1] = "ETH";
    path[2] = "USD";
    path[3] = "LASTMARKET";
    req.addStringArray("path", path);
    sendChainlinkRequestTo(_oracle, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
  }

  function fulfillEthereumPrice(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _price)
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
  {
    emit RequestEthereumPriceFulfilled(_requestId, _price);
    currentPrice = _price;
  }

  function fulfillEthereumChange(bytes32 _requestId, int256 _change)
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
  {
    emit RequestEthereumChangeFulfilled(_requestId, _change);
    changeDay = _change;
  }

  function fulfillEthereumLastMarket(bytes32 _requestId, bytes32 _market)
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
  {
    emit RequestEthereumLastMarket(_requestId, _market);
    lastMarket = _market;
  }

  function getChainlinkToken() public view returns (address) {
    return chainlinkTokenAddress();
  }

  function withdrawLink() public onlyOwner {
    LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
    require(link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))), "Unable to transfer");
  }

  function cancelRequest(
    bytes32 _requestId,
    uint256 _payment,
    bytes4 _callbackFunctionId,
    uint256 _expiration
  )
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    cancelChainlinkRequest(_requestId, _payment, _callbackFunctionId, _expiration);
  }

  function stringToBytes32(string memory source) private pure returns (bytes32 result) {
    bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(source);
    if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
      return 0x0;
    }

    assembly { // solhint-disable-line no-inline-assembly
      result := mload(add(source, 32))
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the error message you're getting and code example to reproduce your issue... The [0x089bD4...](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xC89bD4E1632D3A43CB03AAAd5262cbe4038Bc571#code) address is a proxy contract on Ethereum Rinkeby network, that redirects requests to a [Rinkeby copy](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x01be23585060835e02b77ef475b0cc51aa1e0709#code) of the Chainlink contract.

Comment: Could you edit your question to ask what you're looking for? It sounds like the question is "what does the LINK_TOKEN_POINTER do" if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LINK_TOKEN_POINTER` is a contract that is hard-coded with pointers to the LINK token on various chains. This is so that the contract knows which LINK token to use.

For a chain like harmony, the LINK token pointer probably has not been added for that chain.

To get around this, you'll want to manually set the LINK token, like so:

```
constructor(address _link) public {
        if (_link == address(0)) {
            setPublicChainlinkToken();
        } else {
            setChainlinkToken(_link);
        }
```

It looks like there isn't a LINK token on the Harmony chain yet, so you could deploy a dummy LINK token and point the address to that.

Comment: Thanks Patrick!  The Harmony team has already deployed a LINK token onto their testnet and the address is 0xac8bD2b27d45D582a3882E33F626F4e3d3F49C92

Comment: Ah! Then all you have to do is use that address on the `setChainlinkToken` function!